# How to install Dynomite database on Windows using Windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, git

I am trying to configure the dynomite database for conductor application. I followed the steps given in the link https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite. The dynomite application is cloned but rest of the commands are not recognized as Windows commands on cmd nor on git bash. Please help me to install the dynomite for the Windows and configure it for the conductor application?

Comment: Please provide some code examples for your current issue

Comment: dynomite as found on github seems to target just unix-alike systems like linux or mac. If you have Win10, you could try its integrated ubuntu environment, it's pretty complete and functional. Otherwise you could try cygwin. Or, of course, a mac or (virtual) linux box.

Comment: Thank you. With cygwin its not working and I dont want to run it on virtual OS.